# Javascript/ExtJS: Ext.getCmp('') leads to TypeError ... is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, typeerror, extjs3

I had some code and it used to work fine, now it doesn't anymore. I have a set of results, displayed in a GridPanel and I have a textfield to filter the results. When there is more than 3 letters entered, it will filter the display results accordingly.
There is a listener in the textfield that will react to values being entered. Once something has been entered, it fires the following commands:

```
grid  = Ext.getCmp('shopGrid');
console.log(grid);
store = grid.getStore();
console.log(store);

if (strLen >= 3) {
    store.filter('NAME', input, true, false);

} else {
    store.clearFilter();
    store.load();
}
```

I have added console.log() to see what's going on. I get the grid put out into the console and it's an object with all kinds of elements, just a I would expect. It doesn't go any furhter though and terminates with the error message:
"TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...).getStore is not a function"

I have encountered this kind of error message before, but I don't fully understand what it's trying to tell me yet, as my understanding of the inner workings of Javascript is rather limited. Within ExtJS the function getStore() is only defined for GridPanels. Could my problem be that getCmp() serves me with a standard object rather then a GridPanel? But then there is only one type of object within Javascript, right?
Anyways, I'm using Ext Version 3.4.1. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have set `grid` to be `Ext.getCmp('shopGrid').getView()`, so it is actually a reference to the `view`, not to the grid itself.  Take off the `getView()` and it should work.

```
var grid  = Ext.getCmp('shopGrid'),
    store = grid.getStore();
```

Comment: Oh darn. That getView() wasn't supposed to be in there, I already took it out in my example. I was trying around with different functions to see if it had to with that. I tried it in the exact same you have posted, just with the Ext.getCmp('shopGrid'); but it would lead to the same problem. It have a grid object stored in the 'grid'-variable but when I try to get the store, I'd be having the same error message.

Comment: In that case, please give the code where `shopGrid` is defined.  `getStore` should definitely work if `shopGrid` is a valid `GridPanel`, and there are no other components with the id of `shopGrid`